# Update the sibling component only

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the code below, how can I update only Component B and not Component A (or the Parent Component)

Component A:

```
const A = ({ data, clickCallback }) => {
  console.debug('A');

  return (<button onClick={clickCallback}>Component A</button>)
};
```

Component B:

```
const B = ({ filteredData }) => {
  console.debug('B');

  return <h1>Component B: {filteredData}</h1>;
};
```

Parent Component:

```
function Parent() {
    console.debug('parent');
    const [data, setData] = useState(0);
    const handleClick = () => {
      setData(data + 1);
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <A clickCallback={handleClick}/>
        <B filteredData={data} />
      </div>
    );
}
```

So when clicking on the Component A button, I only see console.debug('B') in the console?

```
parent
A
B
B
B
...
```

Here is the link to the working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-lehmann-kme8d?file=/src/index.js:233-245

NOTE: I have tried wrapping the handleClick inside a `useCallback()` but, still in the console I see:

```
parent
A
B
parent
A
B
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With functional components, they are rerendered when their parent component rerenders. I.E. When `Parent` rerenders, then both `A and` B` will be rerendered in the "render phase" in order to compute a diff. This *should not* be confused with rendering to the DOM during the "commit phase".

You can wrap `A` in the `memo` Higher Order Component and pass a custom equality function that returns true/false if the previous and next props are equal.

[memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

> By default it will only shallowly compare complex objects in the props
> object. If you want control over the comparison, you can also provide
> a custom comparison function as the second argument.
>
> ```
> function MyComponent(props) {
>   /* render using props */
> }
> function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
>   /*
>   return true if passing nextProps to render would return
>   the same result as passing prevProps to render,
>   otherwise return false
>   */
> }
> export default React.memo(MyComponent, areEqual);
> ```

I suggest also correctly console logging in an `useEffect` so you truly know when the component is rerendered to the DOM.

A functional state update should also be used to update the `data` state so the state value isn't closed over in the callback scope.

```
const A = ({ data, clickCallback }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.debug("A");
  });

  return <button onClick={clickCallback}>Component A</button>;
};

const MemoA = memo(
  A,
  (prevProps, nextProps) => prevProps.data === nextProps.data
);

const B = ({ filteredData }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.debug("B");
  });

  return <h1>Component B: {filteredData}</h1>;
};

function Parent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.debug("parent");
  });
  const [data, setData] = useState(0);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setData(data => data + 1); // <-- functional update
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <MemoA clickCallback={handleClick} />
      <B filteredData={data} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit update-the-sibling-component-only]

Comment: In the CodeSandbox link you've provided, the onClick event only fires one time, it won't increment the counter after it is clicked once.

Comment: @A-Sharabiani Oops, lost an edit in there at some point. The `handleClick` callback in the parent should use a functional update (`setData(data => data + 1);`) so the `data` value isn't closed over. I updated the sandbox, please try again.

Comment: you mentioned "with functional components...." I tried converting it to class components here: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-hopper-i0xq0?file=/src/index.js, notice all Parent, A, B 's render() functions get called everytime. Is there a way to fix this for the class components as well?

Comment: @A-Sharabiani: IMO, you think it is like a bug because you used `fixed`. It is the nature of React. Rerenders does not mean not optimized.

Comment: @A-Sharabiani Sorry if that bit was confusing, class-based components work the same way, it's all the same react component lifecycle. When a component renders it renders its *entire* subtree. This is the part that happens in the "render phase" I alluded to. React needs to compute a diff to know what needs to be flushed to the DOM. [React lifecycle diagram](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/)